# How to remove right side extra space in video-view?

Tags: android

I am trying to stream video in video view over HTTP video URL . I am getting a gray space right side of the video. I already set the width as match_parent. I want to play video in total screen width ... can anyone suggest what to do?

Xml is-

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <VideoView android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/previewimg"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"    />
    <!--    ImageView button press video get start and remove the background Image of the -->    
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:src="@drawable/buttonredplay2"
    />
   </FrameLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

The video_view VideoURI set by an AsyncTask, called in "onCreate" method.
[image: fig 1]
At first the video_view display perfect is describe in fig:1.

But when video url linked with the video_view it create problem which I describe .
[image: fig 2]

Comment: Please Share ur XML code..

Comment: Hi am sending the XML in Answer .Please have a look.